# How to place objects when clicking onto mesh Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

So I have this mesh that I generate using perlin noise

[image: Mesh Screenshot]

What I want to do is to be able to click to place an object in the game. My ultimate goal is to have a menu so you can place different objects but I want to just try to get a cube to work. I tried RayCasting:

```
public class Raycast : MonoBehaviour
{  

    Ray myRay;      // initializing the ray
    RaycastHit hit; // initializing the raycasthit
    public GameObject objectToinstantiate;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        myRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(myRay, out hit))
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Instantiate(objectToinstantiate, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log(hit.point);
        }
    }
```

I could not get this to work... I had no real idea how to use this script either (like what object to place it on) I tried just making a cube and putting the script on that but It did not work. I got no errors it just did not work.

I also had a mesh collider on my mesh and a box collider on my cube.

Comment: first, do the opposite: test for `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` first because there is no point raycasting if the user didn't click. You currently raycast at each frame. Then what do you mean "Did not work". It instanciated but at the wrong place, or it didn't do anything?

Comment: @BasilePerrenoud has a good point about the order of `if`s (don't bother getting a ray and casting it if the mouse wasn't clicked).  Also, check wether or not your mesh collider is setup properly; is the mesh collider just attached to the GameObject or is the mesh referenced in the collider's mesh property?  Is `isTrigger` selected for the mesh collider?  If yes, you'll have to manage the [QueryInteractionTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QueryTriggerInteraction.html) properly.

Comment: @BasilePerrenoud Nothing happened... I will change the order now...

Comment: I am now getting the error

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Raycast.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Raycast.cs:16)

Comment: Did you set objectToinstantiate in the editor? Also you have a `Debug.Log`. What does it print?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are following the tutorial on YouTube "Procedural Landmass Generation", which I would say is an excellent way to understand the basics of procedural content generation.

For your question I would suggest you add a camera on the top of the terrain, from where you will be able to point with your mouse where you want to instantiate the object (the cube for example). You would need a function which raycasts to the your land tiles. Check if its gameobject's tag is "Terrain" and check if there is no water at that current location. If terrain check returns true and water check returns false, then instantiate your desired object at the "hit" position of the raycast.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the script on any object you want. I'd propose the camera. After adding this script-component to the camera, drag your mesh (that you want to instantiate) into the "objectToinstantiate" slot you see in the script.

Then see if it works, and for performance move the `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` up in your code, before you do the raycast, like @Basile said.

Note: This script will work in play-mode on the game-view - not in the editor scene-view.

If you'd like this to work too, you should add `[ExecuteInEditMode]` above the `public class ...` line. But be careful with those, it's sometimes hard to stop those scripts :P